# French grammar books with exercises and answer key for self study (A2 - B2)

Tags: resource-request, physical-resources, grammar, french

I am looking for a grammar book or series of grammar books for French that match the following criteria:

- the book or books must be in French, i.e. all grammar rules and instructions must be in French (not English, Spanish, German, ...);
- content should be organised in chapters that first explain a set of grammar rules and then provide a number of exercises that apply these rules;
- there must be an answer key (the answer key may be a separate volume);
- the book must be appropriate for self study (the presence of an answer key is not sufficient; some books of this type are intended for teachers of French).

I am looking for books for the levels A2 - B2. The first three criteria may be easy to fulfil, but the last criterion is essential and it may not be obvious whether a book matches this criterion just by looking at the book cover in an online bookshop. Answers that are based on personal experience using such books would be especially appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

So far, I have found the following books:

- Grégoire, Maïa; Thievenaz Odile: [*Grammaire progressive du français - Niveau intermédiaire*](https://www.cle-international.com/adolescents/grammaire-progressive-du-francais-niveau-intermediaire-4eme-edition-livre-cd-livre-web-9782090381030.html). 4th edition. CLE International, 2017. ISBN 978-2-09-038103-0.
  This is a book for the CEFR levels A2 and B1. There is a separate answer key: [*Grammaire progressive du français - Niveau intermédiaire - Corrigés*](https://www.cle-international.com/adolescents/grammaire-progressive-du-francais-niveau-intermediaire-corriges-4eme-dition-9782090381047.html). 4th edition. CLE International, 2017. ISBN 978-2-09-038104-7.
- Boulares, Michèle; Frerot, Jean-Louis: [*Grammaire progressive du français - Niveau avancé*](https://www.cle-international.com/grammaire-progressive-du-francais-niveau-avance-livre-cd-2eme-edition-nouvelle-couverture-9782090382082.html). 2nd ddition. CLE International, 2017. ISBN 978-2-09-038208-2.
  This is a book for the CEFR levels B1 and B2. There is a separate answer key: *Grammaire progressive du français - Niveau avancé - Corrigés*. 2nd edition. CLE International, 2012. ISBN 978-2090381191.
- Grégoire, Maïa; Kostucki, Alina: [*Grammaire progressive du français - Niveau perfectionnement*](https://www.cle-international.com/adolescents/grammaire-progressive-du-francais-niveau-perfectionnement-livre-cd-nouvelle-couverture-9782090382099.html). CLE International, 2017 (2012). ISBN 978-2-09-038209-9.
  This is a book for the CEFR levels B2, C1 and C2. There is a separate answer key: [*Grammaire progressive du français - Niveau perfectionnement - Corrigés*](https://www.cle-international.com/grammaire-progressive-du-francais-niveau-perfectionnement-corriges-9782090353600.html). CLE International, 2012. ISBN 978-2-09-035360-0.
- Penfornis, Jean-Luc: [*Grammaire progressive du français de affaires- Niveau intermédiaire*](https://www.cle-international.com/adolescents/grammaire-progressive-du-francais-de-affaires-niveau-intermediaire-livre-cd-livre-web-nouvelle-9782090380682.html). CLE International. ISBN 978-2-09-038068-2.
  This book focuses on French for business for the CEFR levels A2 and B1. There is a separate answer key: *Grammaire progressive du français des affaires - Niveau intermédiaire*. CLE International.
- Boulares, Michèle; Grand-Clement, Odile: [*Conjugaison progressive du français - Niveau intermédiaire*](https://www.cle-international.com/adolescents/conjugaison-progressive-du-francais-niveau-intermediaire-livre-cd-2eme-edition-nouvelle-couverture-9782090382150.html). CLE International. ISBN 978-2-09-038215-0.
  This is a book for the CEFR levels A2 and B1 that focuses on verb conjugations. There is a separate answer key: [*Conjugaison progressive du français - Niveau intermédiaire - Corrigés*](https://www.cle-international.com/adolescents/conjugaison-progressive-du-francais-niveau-intermediaire-corriges-2eme-edition-nouvelle-couverture-9782090384512.html). CLE International. ISBN 978-2-09-038451-2.